# Should I use a voltage regulator in tandem with a voltage divider to get 12V, 5V, and 3V from 14V power supply?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider, circuits

I am assembling a circuit that requires 12V, 5V, and 3V. I have a 14V power supply. To create the 12V, 5V, and 3V rails, should I use a 12V voltage regulator and then multiple voltage dividers to get the 5V and 3V rails. Or, would it be better to connect a 12V, 5V, and 3V voltage regulator in parallel? Thanks!

These voltages would be used for stepper motors among other devices. So, definitely a varying load.

Comment: If the 3 V and 5 V are rails you shouldn't use a voltage divider, as the voltage divider output varies considerably with increasing load. If they're just reference voltages you can use a voltage divider (perhaps with an op amp buffer).

Comment: You need a regulator for each voltage. And better a switching, not a linear one.

Comment: Difficult to answer without knowing the current demands for each rail. It might be best to use three switching regulators, or it might be better to use e.g. a linear for 12V, switcher for 5V and a linear for 3V driven off the 5V.

Comment: Hi, thanks all! The voltages would be for stepper motors with a max current draw of 2.5 A. So, based on what you said, voltage divider would not work. I edited the question as such.

Comment: it would be better to connect the 3.3v to the 5v, and the 5v to the 12v instead of feeding them all 14v. That way you spread the heat out and/or reduce wasted power.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to make a discrete driver when these are better options to buy.  Use 14V with a reasonable current limit (heat rise) https://www.amazon.ca/Longruner-LK02-Arduino-Professional-Mechanical/dp/B07NXP6HST/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=a4988&linkCode=g13&linkId=3d405814921cfd3b11a5c53327086e43&qid=1645827345&sr=8-5.. No need for 12V reg

Comment: Please be more specific re max currents on each supply. It matters if you care about heat dissipation and energy use. For 12 5 3V please stae Imax for each. With 14V in 3 V is 3/14 ~= 20% efficient with linear regulators. With eg 2A out that's 6W out and 28W in so 22W dissipated as heat.  Switching regulators are probably a very good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voltage dividers as in resistor dividers are not proper regulators for any load that may change. As the load changes the current through the resistors changes so the voltage changes. Not to mention potential heat issues. Resistor dividers should only be used for very light loads or references. At worst maybe if you have a fixed load and are stuck on an island with no shipping.

You can use proper regulators either in parallel or in series. If they are linear regulators, the decision will be based on where you want the waste heat to be. If they are switching regulators, the decision will be on which gives you the better efficiency based on input and output and current.

In either case you want to ensure proper heat sinking, and keep any maximum voltage in mind.